# Consulta SQL de Oracle arroja resultados distintos al correrse desde Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Estoy ejecutando una consulta en mi [sqldeveloper](/questions/tagged/sqldeveloper) y me arroja el resultado correcto `>>24 piezas`.

Cuando transporto este query a java me arroja un numero de piezas diferente `>>39`

Aquí mi código :

```
$_Query = "select sum(nvl(ln.cantidad,0)) ACUSES_ENTREGADOS "
           + " FROM    xxqp.xxqp_rec_diario_tbl    rd, "
           + " xxqp.xxqp_diario_hd_tbl     hdr, "
           + " xxqp.xxqp_diario_ln_tbl     ln "
           + " WHERE 1 = 1 "
           + " AND     rd.diario_id    =   hdr.diario_id "
           + " AND     hdr.diario_id   =   ln.diario_id "
           + " AND     ln.codigo      IS   NOT NULL "
           + " AND LN.ESTATUS=11 "
           + " AND     ln.csc_id       =   rd.csc_id "
           + " AND XXQP.XXQP_COMPROBANTE_DIARIO_PKG.XXQP_CATEGORIA_LINEA_DIARIO(Pni_diario_id => rd.diario_id "
           + " ,Pni_csc_id    => ln.csc_id "
           + " ,Pni_pieza_id  => Ln.pieza_id) = 'Acuses' "
           + " AND TO_CHAR(hdr.FECHA_CIERRE_DIARIO,'DD/MM/YYYY')='13/09/2016' "
           + " AND hdr.COLABORADOR_ID='108977'";

            clon = Gdr.getCon(2);
            st1 = clon.createStatement();
            rs1 = st1.executeQuery($_Query);
            while (rs1.next()) {
                     acusesEntregados = rs1.getInt("acuses_entregados");        
                     if (r == 0) {%>
                           <tr bgcolor='white' ALIGN='CENTER'>
                           <%
                         r = 1;
                     } else {
                        r = 0;
                        %> 
                       <tr bgcolor='#E6E6E6' ALIGN='CENTER'>
                       <%                                  
                     }%>

            <td><%=acusesEntregados%></td>
```

Tengo la sospecha de que no esta respetando esta linea del query :

```
AND   XXQP.XXQP_COMPROBANTE_DIARIO_PKG.XXQP_CATEGORIA_LINEA_DIARIO(Pni_diario_id => rd.diario_id 
        ,Pni_csc_id    => ln.csc_id 
       ,Pni_pieza_id  => Ln.pieza_id) = 'Acuses'
```

No se si tenga que meter alguna configuración o tenga que modificar el código.

Comment: No tengo ni idea de java... pero la verdad es que suena bastante raro... ¿la sql funciona perfectamente en el sql developer? ¿y tiene la misma estructura de "array embebido" en la query? Para saber si es exactamente esa parte de la sql que te falta, ¿si la lanzas en el developer comentando con /**/ esa parte te da los 39 resultados?